# First React Native app: Open web shows blank website

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build a websaite/app using Rect Native. I've installed Visual Studio Code for programming.

I am running Windows 10.

When I start npm with command "npm start" I get the following option:

```
› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press d │ show developer tools
› shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

› Press ? │ show all commands
```

Now I open web using "w". After few seconds a blank website appears with the apps Icon and Title, but no content.

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Whois",
    "slug": "Whois",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "whois",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "expo build:web",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d web-build",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.67.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Websites code that is generated when I press "w"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!-- 
      This viewport works for phones with notches.
      It's optimized for gestures by disabling global zoom.
     -->
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.00001, viewport-fit=cover"
    />
    <title>Whois</title>
    <style>
      /**
       * Extend the react-native-web reset:
       * https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/packages/react-native-web/src/exports/StyleSheet/initialRules.js
       */
      html,
      body,
      #root {
        width: 100%;
        /* To smooth any scrolling behavior */
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* Allows content to fill the viewport and go beyond the bottom */
        min-height: 100%;
      }
      #root {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-basis: auto;
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
      }

      html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        /* Prevent text size change on orientation change https://gist.github.com/tfausak/2222823#file-ios-8-web-app-html-L138 */
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        height: calc(100% + env(safe-area-inset-top));
      }

      body {
        display: flex;
        /* Allows you to scroll below the viewport; default value is visible */
        overflow-y: auto;
        overscroll-behavior-y: none;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
      }
      /* Enable for apps that support dark-theme */
      /*@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        body {
          background-color: black;
        }
      }*/
    </style>
  <link rel="manifest" href="\manifest.json"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="\favicon-16.png"></link><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="\favicon-32.png"></link><link rel="shortcut icon" href="\favicon.ico"></link></head>

  <body>
    <!-- 
      A generic no script element with a reload button and a message.
      Feel free to customize this however you'd like.
    -->
    <noscript>
      <form
        action=""
        style="
          background-color: #fff;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          z-index: 9999;
        "
      >
        <div
          style="
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            line-height: 24px;
            margin: 10%;
            width: 80%;
          "
        >
          <p>Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.</p>
          <p style="margin: 20px 0;">
            <button
              type="submit"
              style="
                background-color: #4630eb;
                border-radius: 100px;
                border: none;
                box-shadow: none;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: bold;
                line-height: 20px;
                padding: 6px 16px;
              "
            >
              Reload
            </button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </noscript>
    <!-- The root element for your Expo app. -->
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```